# How to handle ArgumentException thrown by generated XAML-code in UWP App

Tags: c#, xaml, exception, uwp

i've got several Textboxes in my UWP app which are bound to float properties (two-way). I use compiled bindings. At this time there is no own "code-behind" for these textboxes. Now i got the problem that the app crashes on simple mistypings (for instance if the user types letters instead of numbers). I wonder how i could handle these exceptions without modifying the generated code.

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.QtyGoodEntered, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="36" x:Name="QtyGoodTextBox"/>
```

The App crashes when trying to convert the letters to float.

```
 case 33: // Views\ProdFeedbackView.xaml line 191
this.obj33 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox)target;
                        (this.obj33).LostFocus += (global::System.Object sender, global::Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e) =>
{
  if (this.initialized)
  {
    // Update Two Way binding
    this.dataRoot.ViewModel.QtyGoodEntered = (global::System.Double) global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue(typeof(global::System.Double), this.obj33.Text);
  }
```

Regards
Nils

Comment: Do you know about the `Converter` property? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension#properties-that-you-can-set-with-xbind

Comment: Instead of catching an exception you shouldn't let user type in any letters or so.

Comment: @Florian Moser You mean i should write an IValueConverter and handle things there? Sounds good. I will try that tomorrow and let you know. My current solution is to subscribe the App.UnhandledException inside my View class, but i'm not so happy with that.

Comment: @Marian Yes i could write my own "code-behind" but i was looking for a solution to stick with XAML if possible. Florinans suggestion sounds promising.

Comment: There are, in my opinion, better ways how to achieve that. For example [TextBoxMask XAML Property](http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/extensions/TextBoxMask/) from UWP Community Toolkit.

Comment: Using it you don't have to write new converter for each type of data.

Comment: I'm goin to check that, thank you

Answer (score 0):

ok i got following options.

- Using converter (thanks to Florian Moser)
- [TextBoxMask Property](http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/extensions/TextBoxMask/) (thanks to Marian Dolinsky)
- Catching UnhandledException

Due to lack of time i stick with the converter solution but i think the TextBoxMask Property is worth a try. Catching the UnhandledException is the worst solution in my opinion.
This is what my converter looks like. In case of an exception the content defaults to 0.0. Thats all i needed.

```
    public class StringToDoubleConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            try
            {
                return System.Convert.ToString((double)value);
            }
            catch
            {
                return "";
            }

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            try
            {
            return System.Convert.ToDouble((string)value);
            }
            catch
            {
                return 0.0;
            }
        }
    }
```

And thats the XAML part

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.QtyGoodEntered, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource StringToDoubleConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="36" x:Name="QtyGoodTextBox"/>
```